# Safari Mobile and object-position property

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

I have a question regarding Safari Mobile and CSS `object-position/object-fit`  property.

I've tried to use it, but it doesn't work for me.

I've seen 2 different answers(Safari Mobile supporting this property and doesn't support)

There is my example:

```css
img {
  object-position: 0 -300px;
  width: 112px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

I'm using CSS sprites for menu icons as `img`, not as `background`.

How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS safari **does** support `object-fit` **however** doesn't support `object-position`

See [Can I use CSS3 object-fit/object-position ?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

> <sup>1</sup> Partial support in Safari refers to support for `object-fit` but not `object-position`.

[image: SS]

---

A possible solution is using `background` with `background-position`

Other solution, given you are using icons, would be using glyphs, from Font-Awesome or Glyphicons, just to name a few.

---

Here is a good article about [CSS sprites](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: yes, you are right, It was my mistake. Thanks a lot!